# Ошибка в Codeception Selenium при запуске теста

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Настройки `acceptance.suite.yml`

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
        - PhpBrowser
        - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
          WebDriver:
                 url: 'http://localhost/EnglishAndComands/'
                 port: 4444
                 browser: 'firefox'
                 wait: 10
                 restart: true
                 capabilities:
                   unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
          PhpBrowser:
                      url: 'http://localhost/EnglishAndComands/'
```

Селениум запущен. При запуске теста происходит следующая ошибка

```
Running WelcomeCept ... PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions::switchToIframe() in /var/www/html/test/tests/_support/_generated/AcceptanceTesterActions.php on line 2760

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions::switchToIframe() in /var/www/html/test/tests/_support/_generated/AcceptanceTesterActions.php on line 2760
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка не связана с селениумом. Это проблема codeception.
generated/AcceptanceTesterActions.php это файл который создаётся при запуске build.
Он собирается из нескольких частей - модулей и Тестера из _support
Там дублировалась switchToIframe - о чём и говорит ошибка.

Comment: Пожалуйста используйте в правках выделение слов `кодом` для кода, а не для всего подряд. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/41496